# Best way to find matches of several substrings in string?

Tags: php, string, search, strpos

I have `$a=array('1str','2str','3str')` and `$str ='123 2str 3str 1str'` 
and trying to do a simple thing - find the position of each item of `$a` in $str.

It's easy to be done with loops and `strpos`, but I'm curious what is the best (and short, actually) way to get the positions?

Actually I need to get the nearest of the found items in string (2str)

Comment: If `strpos` is easy enough and working then I would suggest you stick with it.  If performance is an issue then you should write yourself a benchmark and see how your implementation holds up over many iterations.  Some code of what you are doing right now would be good to give others an idea of what you are working with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need all offsets, could also use [preg_match_all](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) function and flag `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE`

```
if(preg_match_all('/'.implode('|', $a).'/', $str, $out, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE))
  print_r($out[0]);
```

Useful if you need to match such as `\b` [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) or do caseless matching using the `i` [flag](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php).

*As @mike.k commented*: If `$a` contains [characters with special meaning inside a regex pattern](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special), need to escape those first: `array_map(function ($v) { return preg_quote($v, "/"); }, $a)`

---

To get the one that's closest to start, don't need all offsets. Could do that with `preg_match` and the [simple pattern](https://regex101.com/r/cB6xT5/1) `1str|2str|3str` ([see test at eval.in](https://eval.in/398559)).

```
if(preg_match('/'.implode('|', $a).'/', $str, $out, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE))
  echo "The substring that's closest to start is \"".$out[0][0]."\" at offset ".$out[0][1];
```

> The substring that's closest to start is "2str" at offset 4

---

If you don't need offset/regex at all, another idea for the first match: Sorting with [usort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) by pos

```
usort($a, function ($x, $y) use (&$str) {
  return (strpos($str, $x) < strpos($str, $y)) ? -1 : 1;
});
```

[echo $a[0];](https://eval.in/398654) > `2str`  (anonymous functions with usort *require at least PHP 5.3*)

Comment: Nice! Forgot about that flag. One improvement: change `$a` to `array_map('preg_quote', $a)`

Comment: True, it would probably need to be done beforehand with a `foreach`

Comment: in my case there should be another loop to find in results the nearest to the start of the string

Comment: @elDude You mean the one, that's closest to start of string? See updated answer.

Comment: if you mean that `$out[0]` is the closest of substrings then this is what I'm looking for

Comment: @elDude my 2nd and 3rd example give the match from input array, that's closest to the start of string. The usort method would be fine if you don't need regex, should have good performance. [Test it at eval.in](https://eval.in/398654) with different inputs.

Comment: just tested.. Works.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it this way with `array_map()`

```
$a = array('1str', '2str', '3str');
$str ='123 2str 3str 1str';

function my_strpos($needle) {
    global $str;
    return strpos($str, $needle);
}

$positions = array_map('my_strpos', $a);
```

`print_r($positions);` gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 14
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 9
)
```

Comment: good enough. Thank you

Comment: I think he wants `$a[array_keys($positions, min($positions))[0]]`